# jQuery If statement not rendering

Tags: visualforce, jquery

Trying to add a condition to this jQuery so that if a checkbox is selected and then selection is removed, the selection class will be removed but it isn't working.

What am I missing please?

```
j$ = jQuery.noConflict();
j$(document).ready(function() {
    j$('.checkBox').click(function() {
        if (this.checked) {
            j$(this).closest('tr').find('.inputStatus').val('Completed');
            j$(this).closest('tr').addClass("selected");
        } else {
            j$(this).closest('tr').removeClass("selected");
        }
    });
});
```

Table
    
                        
                         
                       
                        {!cType__c}
                        {!c.Customer__c}
                        {!c.Subject__c}
                        {!c.Task__c}

```
                    <td width="80"><apex:outputText value="{0, date, MMM'-' d'-'yyyy}">
                        <apex:param value="{!c.Due__c}" /> 
                        </apex:outputText>
                    </td>
                </tr>
```

Comment: I've changed my answer - it should make more sense now.

Comment: Lizzy, the question was closed because the question itself (and thus the expected answer) did not appear closely related or specific for the salesforce platform and technologies.  While the jquery is on a visualforce page and using salesforce data, neither of those appear (based on the question) to be part of the issue you're trying to overcome.

Comment: Sorry Gents!   I probably should have worded it differently because when it Fiddle it, everything works fine but not on the VF page because of my selection I think.

I will read the rules more closely and sorry for offending!

Comment: Added update that should solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

The `checked` attribute is not a boolean - it's an attribute, so it's not necessarily true - so your if statement is likely to always evaluate to true, regardless of the value of checked.

Try wrapping `this` in the `jQuery` object and evaluating it this way:

Change your `if(this.checked)` line to:

```
if ($(this).is(':checked')){
```

Also, while the structure of the table is not all there, to select a particular row of a `select` element, you would generally do something like this:

```
 var row = $(this).closest('tr');
 row.find("td select.inputStatus option[value=saab]").attr("selected", true);
```

(This is similar to your other question on StackOverflow)

Comment: thanks for replying.  That makes a lot of sense.  I still have a problem somewhere because it no longer selects any row and changes the value or adds the class.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you add a snipped of your table structure, with all the td and input classes present so I check that your find is working?